AC Issues in two story home
hoping to get some direction on this situation. I live in Arizona, super hot here obviously, and I have an issue that is very opposite to most of the AC issues people online seem to complain about.
So I have one AC unit for a 2,000 sq ft house, with two thermostats, one upstairs and one down. Quite often during the summer, my upstairs floor gets super cold, while my downstairs gets super hot. I almost always have both thermostats set to 76. When I experience the issue, downstairs will be at around 79 trying to get down to 76, while upstairs will be at 68 (I am assuming since there is one unit it's just still running here because downstairs is).
The particularly worst part about it is the room downstairs in the front of my house, it gets super hot in there, sometimes around 84, and it's awful. I keep all vents in the house fully open at all times, and regularly change my filters, every 3 months during the summer.
I'm open to calling a professional, just trying to explore any cheaper options first, appreciate the help!!

Might just be a tuning issue.  Opening/closing dampers to adjust air flow to different areas.  Make sure that room has full open dampers, upstairs is closed a bit more.  Yes it is a pain in the neck to get it right and will require a few days to to get it right. settings.

Where is the sun in all this?  Sunbeams are 300 BTU/hr per square foot. With the very poor albedo of most roof and wall coatings, most of that ends up heating up building structure when then radiates into PARTS of the house.   A lot of people think about A/C as being "inside air temperature vs outside air temperature", nope, it's all about solar gain.

What's the window situation in the various locations?

Since you have two thermostats and one AC unit you must have what they call dampers
Dampers are controlled airflow valves, that adjust according to the control board set up.
Go to the control board and adjust dampers setting (partially closing the upper floor and opening the lover floor.
